# Ese perro campeón ni se timbró - meaning of "timbrarse"

Tags: definiciones

I have heard the following sentence in Narcos (a TV series which takes place in Colombia):

> Ese perro campeón ni se timbró.

Context: Pablo Escobar bets with his partner Gacha that Gacha's drug-sniffing dog wouldn't be able to detect the cocaine mixed with the glass fiber in a hull of a boat. When the dog indeed doesn't detect the cocaine, Pablo says the line above.

What does "timbrarse" mean here? The only meanings of "timbrar" I see in the Word Reference dictionary are "to stamp" and "to crest".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an idiom localized to Colombia at https://en.bab.la/dictionary/spanish-english/timbrarse:

> **timbrarse**: "ponerse nervioso", Colombia, colloquial *to get edgy, to get jumpy* {vb} [coll.]

So, I guess your sentence would be *That champ of a dog didn't bat an eyelash [get nervous in the slightest].*